# How do I make sure a value is not returned if it is connected to multiple values, one which is undesired?

Tags: mysql

My question isn't perfectly phrased, but basically here's the question.

I have two columns in a table "works". One column is a list of last names, and the other is a list of cities where the people live.

I don't want my query to return anybody who lives in Chicago.

My current code is:

```
select lives.last_name 
from lives  
where lives.city <> "Chicago";
```

But some people live in both Chicago and somewhere else, say Miami, and they still show up. How do I only return people who don't live in Chicago without using group or count functions (not that far yet)

Thanks

Comment: If a person can reside in more than one city would be more coherent to create a table allocates them to receive the person's ID, ID/city name.

But in your case you can use binary search with.

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select a.last_name
from lives a
where not exists (select last_name
                   from lives b
                   where a.last_name = b.last_name
                       and city = 'chicago')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b633d/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT last_name
FROM lives
WHERE last_name NOT IN
   (
     SELECT last_Name
     FROM lives
     WHERE city = 'Chicago'
   )
```

Comment: Thank you. Is "Not In" the equivalent to "except" or something else?

Comment: The EXCEPT operator returns all of the distinct rows from the query to the left of the EXCEPT operator when there is no matching rows in the right query.  EXCEPT operator works the same way NOT IN.

Comment: [See Here: Comparison EXCEPT operator vs. NOT IN](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/22/sql-server-2005-comparison-except-operator-vs-not-in/)

Answer (score 0):

You may group on last name selecting all cities and then filtering records not containign Chicago:

```
Select Last_name, City
from lives
group by Last_name
having group_concat(city) not Regexp 'Chicago'
```